# Route traffic from iPhone to desktop and back

Tags: http, proxy, iphone, burp-suite

I have some iOS app to pentest, and the target server is accessible only through the jailbroken iPhone's APN. My problem is, that I want to configure the traffic in such way so I can intercept and tamper HTTP request / responses in my desktop using Burp, and route them back to iPhone:

`iPhone` → `Burp` → `iPhone` → `Server`

Should I install HTTP proxy on the iPhone, or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I maybe completely wrong because I don't have a phone to test it, but if your computer provided a WiFi access point, then the phone would route to it. If you tethered your computer back to your phone, I believe all tethered traffic goes over the cellular side. If that works, then you have a nice circular route without any need to be jailbroken.

Since you are jailbroken anyway, though, you can accomplish the same thing by using pf with the route-to filter to force traffic from the PC to the outside interface. Appropriately modify the commands found at http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/pools.html#outgoing

Comment: I might assuming something completely wrong, but isn't the phone needs a proxy listener in order to get back the HTTP request?